# Enormous memory (native heap) increase setting a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, memory

I get an increase of native heap usage of 6 MB when I'm expecting an increase of about 0.1 MB

How I came to these numbers:

```
Log.d("test", "before setting layout");
showMemoryStats();

setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

Log.d("test", "after setting layout");
showMemoryStats();
```

Where showMemoryStats is:

```
public static void showMemoryStats() {
    Log.i("test", "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    Log.i("test", "showing memory stats in xx");
    double nativeUsage = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize(); 
    Log.i("test", "nativeUsage: " + nativeUsage);
    //current heap size 
    double heapSize =  Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    Log.i("test", "heapSize: " + heapSize);
    //amount available in heap 
    double heapRemaining = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();   
    Log.i("test", "heapRemaining: " + heapRemaining);
    double memoryAvailable = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() - (heapSize - heapRemaining) - nativeUsage;
    Log.i("test", "memoryAvailable: " + memoryAvailable);
    Log.i("test", "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

The output:

> 07-03 16:50:40.127: D/test(18647): before setting layout
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.127: I/test(18647): ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.127: I/test(18647): showing memory stats in xx
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.127: I/test(18647): nativeUsage: 5706008.0
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.127: I/test(18647): heapSize: 4905968.0
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.127: I/test(18647): heapRemaining: 1815456.0
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.127: I/test(18647): memoryAvailable: 2.4757912E7
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.127: I/test(18647): ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.348: D/dalvikvm(18647): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 100K, 49% free 2924K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 45ms
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.518: D/dalvikvm(18647): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 9K, 49% free 2917K/5639K, external 2700K/3371K, paused 51ms
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.638: D/dalvikvm(18647): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4K, 49% free 2928K/5639K, external 3952K/4356K, paused 51ms
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.698: D/dalvikvm(18647): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 48% free 2933K/5639K, external 5963K/6027K, paused 24ms
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.718: D/test(18647): after setting layout
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.718: I/test(18647): ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.718: I/test(18647): showing memory stats in xx
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.718: I/test(18647): nativeUsage: 1.2101904E7
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.718: I/test(18647): heapSize: 4734944.0
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.718: I/test(18647): heapRemaining: 1716432.0
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.718: I/test(18647): memoryAvailable: 1.8434016E7
>
> 07-03 16:50:40.718: I/test(18647): ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The maths:

12101856 bytes - 5703424 bytes = 6398432 bytes = 6.10202 mb

I went though my layout file and added the size of all the drawables used, and came to a total size of 124 kb -> 0.121094 mb

So what on earth is causing the native heap to increase 6 mb?

I can put the layout file, if somebody ask for it, don't know if it makes sense... just a bunch of layouts with ids and drawables, and as said I already checked the drawables for the size.

Thanks a lot in advance...

**Edit: This was the solution, in my case - in order to summarize the responses and comments: I was storing the images in the folder "drawable" and using a hdpi device. Solution: put the images in folder drawable-hdpi. Reason: The system was stretching my images from "drawable" in order to match hdpi resolution, although they were already in hdpi resolution. This made them occupy more than 2x of memory than they should.**

Comment: Are you populating drawables with something that could use more memory? What are your drawables? Images or fields?

Comment: The drawables are either bitmaps or XML files referencing bitmaps for pressed / drawable states. Nothing more. Populating: I am populating with dynamic data, but after these lines. As you see there is an output, then setContentView, then output again, nothing else in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Bitmaps take a huge amount of space up.

Each pixel requires 4 Bytes!

So a 1M pixel Image is 4MB!!! I assume you are using many smaller images, but they soon add up.

One way around this is to load the bitmaps at a lower resolution (in most cases you wont notice any difference as they are not being displayed at max res anyway). Look into `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize` for this.

As quoted from android

> Bitmaps take up a lot of memory, especially for rich images like
>   photographs. For example, the camera on the Galaxy Nexus takes photos
>   up to 2592x1936 pixels (5 megapixels). If the bitmap configuration
>   used is ARGB_8888 (the default from the Android 2.3 onward) then
>   loading this image into memory takes about 19MB of memory (2592*1936*4
>   bytes), immediately exhausting the per-app limit on some devices.

[Here is a great link to explain it better](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) .

Comment: I see, interesting. I'll look for a solution. Coming back to this thread when I advance a bit... For now thanks and +1

Comment: @Ixx Cheers. The solution is in the given link. Specifically the first lesson. It has great code snippets that I also use to downsize an image. You pass it your desired image size, and it calculates and then uses `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize` to downsize it appropriately.

Comment: I have also to consider recycle and other tricks, because I'll be loading a lot of different stuff everywhere... this is just the start... But yes, downsizing is a good idea, as long as it still looks perfect, otherwise I get problems here...

Comment: Okay, so I have now a png which is 480 x 800 pixels and that's the view/screen size (I'm using it as the background of the activity). So it's 1:1 pixel on the image and pixel on the screen, or am I wrong? It's occupying 4 mb space. Is there a way to reduce the size without loosing detail on screen? I mean, every pixel I reduce from the image will be missing on screen, since 1:1 (sorry for repeated comment).

Comment: @Ixx An image of that size would take only 1.5MB. (`480x800x4 Bytes`). Depending on how rich a colour you need, you can use `ARGB_4444` instead. This halves the size once again, but also reduces dramatically the number of colours you can use. If you dont need See through, which I assume you wont with a background, then use `RGB_256`. This gives you loads of colours, and Is stored in less than the others. - A definate must

Comment: Actually its `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` not `256`.

Comment: See my last comments in Dude's post, I got 3.4 mb with a 480x800 image, which has transparent areas. I think it should be using ARGB_8888, because I didn't set anything. So it should be like you say 480x800x4, but it's not... in the comment I write how I got the size.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that when android has to draw your drawables on the screen, they are much bigger than when they are in your res folder. If you have for example a PNG that is 100 Kb, then this is the compressed size. When android draws the PNG on the screen, it blows it up to the normal size which is per default (4 Bytes) * (height in pixel) * (width in pixel). This is because it stores 4 byte of color information for every pixel that your image has. This means if your image is for example 800 x 600 pixel that the resulting bitmap that android generates is 800x600x4 bytes = 1920000 bytes = something near 2 Mb.

If you want to get around this problem you have to use smaller images.

Comment: Okay, so I have now a png which is 480 x 800 pixels and that's the view/screen size (I'm using it as the background of the activity). So it's 1:1 pixel on the image and pixel on the screen, or am I wrong? It's occupying 4 mb space. Is there a way to reduce the size without loosing detail on screen? I mean, every pixel I reduce from the image will be missing on screen, since 1:1 (sorry for repeated comment).

Comment: @Doomsknight already explained it pretty accurate. Strange that your size is 4 MB. Where do you get this number from?

Comment: Hi. I did a test with 2 png images, both 480 x 800. One has transparent areas, the other not. The image without transparent areas has 1.7 mb, the other one has 3.456 mb (it was first 4 because it was a bit bigger, scaled it down).  I got that with `background = ((BitmapDrawable)myRootView.getBackground()).getBitmap();
  Log.d("test", "size of img: " + (background.getRowBytes() * background.getHeight() / 1000000d));` and also tracing native heap size.

Comment: What do you get if you do it instead with getByteCount() and divided by 1024 * 1024 (one KiloByte is 1024 Bytes)? `background = ((BitmapDrawable)myRootView.getBackground()).getBitmap(); Log.d("test", "size of img: " + (background.getByteCount() / 1048576d));`

Comment: `background.getByteCount()` Only works with API level 12 and above. Its definitely a better option if available. Try also logging `background.getHeight()` and `background.getWidth()` to see what the actual height and width are when reading.

Comment: @Dude thanks for the correction, wrong math. With 1024*1024 I get 3.295 mb... still very bad number. getByteCount() is as Doomsknight says not available.

Comment: @Doomsknight that gets me near to the problem, got 1200 x 700 !!! I was logging the width and height with a method I found somewhere, using `BitmapFactory.Options` etc. but that returns the dimensions of the original image, not on the view. Now I logged the dimensions of the bitmap, directly, and got 1200 x 700. But why is this, the screen is 480 x 800, the image is 480 x 800. Maybe Android loads different resolution depending on folder? I stored it in "drawable"

Comment: Ok: I finally got it!. I had to store the image in the folder "drawable-hdpi". Now it has the correct size and 1.46 mb!! Thanks a lot for your help, guys. Now I don't know who give the points... :/

Comment: @Ixx who ever was the most helpful *Evil Grin*. lol Im not fussed. Its just really so that if someone else has the same problem, they can see which answer helped them. Im sure there are other answers of mine relating to images that you might find useful anyway. Glad you got it sorted.